"How is it having 2 dogs?" VS "What is it like having 2 dogs?"
How is it having two dogs? (I heard a native english speaker say this.)
But, as a non-native speaker, if I said:
What is it like having two dogs?
Would it be idiomatic, too?

Both are natural. I'd hear #1 as "How is it—having two dogs?" Like "How is it 'having two dogs'?"

On average, I think How is it having two dogs? is more likely if the speaker knows that the addressee has only recently become the owner / keeper of two dogs, whereas What's it like having two dogs? is perfectly natural even if addressed to someone who has always had two dogs. That's because How is it having two dogs? (not particularly idiomatic, imho) sounds to me like a non-native speaker's phrasing for How are finding life with / now you've got two dogs?

@FumbleFingers How is it working at that company? "How is it + verbING + object" is very idiomatic and used all the time in English. How is it having a dog for company?

To me they are not 'exact' and "How is it having two dogs?" requires parsing a couple of times. It sounds like a non-native speaker and isn't idiomatic.

@Lambie how is what working at that company? Your invention? The payroll system?

I disagree that "How is it having two dogs?" sounds non-native and non-idiomatic. My goodness. [Having two dogs can be a lot of work.] There's no reason one can't use a verb phrase after How is. No reason at all. How is it answering the call of the wild? Are you enjoying Alaska?

The How is it having X? format does occur as a minority usage in AmE, but it's got no currency in BrE.

I'm fine with How is / How's living away from home working out?, but I'd never ask How is it living away from home? That pronoun it is a real syntactic stumbling block for me. But perhaps that's just an AmE / BrE usage split.

@FumbleFingers  I think your understanding of the nuanced recency diffference between the two questions is spot on. And for that reason it's puzzling that you don't find the "How is it" version idiomatic.  So, how is it owning an electric SUV? Everything you hoped for? Or have you found yourself stranded on a cold day with dead batteries?

@TimR: Like I said, the "How is it [doing whatever you're now doing]?" format has little currency in BrE. Sure, I can understand it in context, but to me it's a bit of a "garden path" construction. I have to parse quite a bit of text before I can see the difference between How is it working from home? and How is it possible that you are working from home?, which doesn't arise with my preferred How are you finding [it] working from home? Although I see the construction has sometimes been called "dialectal", to me it's "literary" (unusual / complex syntax).

That's to say How is it owning an electric SUV? could easily be confused with How is it [that] you own an electric SUV? if you're not paying attention. On that basis alone, I'd advise learners to give the construction a wide berth.

@FumbleFingers Not an issue at all in AmE.  Maybe the punctuation doesn't quite reveal the parsing rhythms. Insert a comma:   How is it, having your dog walked by a professional dog-walker? Dog seem happier?

I would prefer "what's it like?" in both cases (I'm British). E.g. you might ask a new father "So what's it like being a dad?" or an old employee "What's it like to work there?" The difference between "to work" and "working" comes into this with respect to recency/time.

Yes, these are both idiomatic and mean almost exactly the same thing.
In general, How is __ is likely asking for a short answer that focuses on "good" vs "bad". You hear this phrasing a lot in small-talk or when filling a brief moment at the beginning of a different conversation. Some possible answers might be:

It's great! I'm so glad we got the second one.
It's a lot of work. But I'm hoping it calms down once the puppy is house-broken.

In contrast, What is __ like asks for more description. The answers might start off the same, but the question implies that the asker wants more details. Some example answers could be:

It's great! I'm so glad we got the second one. Now they play together all the time. They're so cute, do you want to see a video?
It's a lot of work. But I'm hoping it calms down once the puppy is house-broken. Currently, they both seem to always need to go out at different times. When the puppy makes a mess on the floor, the older dog tries to pee there too!


I think the point was to show a verb phrase. How is the tea? What's the tea like? is not the form being asked about.

@Lambie that's a good point - do you feel like there is something about verb phrases in this context that is different from a simple noun? Is there something about my answer that you feel doesn't apply here?

It's not that your answer does not apply., It's that a simple noun versus a verb phrase is the difficulty here for learners.
